# How do I integrate my Child Theme into a Custom Template?

Tags: functions, customization, child-theme

I started working on this yesterday, and while I was able to successfully load my child theme, some of the site functionality went haywire.

I suspect that I may need to add some code to my functions.php doc, but I'm not sure and don't want to botch the site again (since the client was not happy this AM when they discovered the problem)

Again, I suspect that I may need to add some "required" script to my functions.php, but don't want to break stuff. Help is much appreciated. Let me know what you need to see . . .

Answer (score 0):

If all you have in your child theme is a style.css file and a functions.php file. I would suspect an issue in functions.php.

if you used the information on this page [Wodpress Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to create your child theme. Then I would suspect an issue with your function names. Try appending your initials to the begging of all your function names and the hook call backs.

Comment: I noticed that the current functions.php file actually references some more styles that I did not notice before. I was going to try adding this code (in the parent theme functions) to the child. 

Do you think this is a bad idea?

http://pastebin.com/D4YqLbjU

Comment: You shouldn't need to, anything in the parent theme will be used, unless you override it in the child theme.